# How to make Android EditText force its container to scroll

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, scrollview

I have an Android app which can create multiple lines each of which contains two spinners and an EditText. If the content gets too wide for the EditText, it breaks into multiple lines and this messes up my layout. So I call setMaxLines(1). But now the EditText scrolls internally. I want the EditText to expand horizontally to fit its content and the containing HorizontalScrollView to scroll. How can I do this?

I tried putting a HorizontalScrollView in a ScrollView and vice versa. Neither way round works. I expected that setting (both) LayoutParams to wrap_content would work but it doesn't.

I haven't included all of the code because it is a big app. Here is the layout XML:-

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- This is an invisible view to request the focus when an EditText gets deleted
                 in order to stop Android highlighting something else.
                 It would be nicer to go back into touch mode,
                 but Android does not provide a way of doing that. -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:text=""
                android:alpha="0"
                android:id="@+id/defineinvisible"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/defineclasslayout">
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The lines containing the EditTexts are added dynamically because the number of them can vary as the app runs.

The code to add a line looks a bit like this (I've left out some irrelevant detail):-

```
public class OrItem extends LinearLayout implements TextWatcher {
    public OrItem(Context context) {
        m_nameSelector = new Spinner(m_context);
        m_contSelector = new Spinner(m_context);
        m_matchString = new EditText(m_context);
        m_matchString.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);            m_matchString.setMaxLines(1);
        m_matchString.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }
    public setup(...) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams ww = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        addView(m_nameSelector, ww);
        addView(m_contSelector, ww);
        m_matchString.setText(sa[2]);
        m_wasEmpty = sa[2].isEmpty();
        m_matchString.addTextChangedListener(this);
        addView(m_matchString, ww);
    }
}
```

The OrItem is added under a hierarchy of LinearLayouts that hangs from defineclasslayout.

I tried inserting

but this goes back to line wrapping inside the EditText.

Comment: Sorry, the end of my question got garbled trying to get rid of the "looks like code" rejection. I tried setMaxLines(1), setSingleLine(), setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_TEXT), and setHorizontalScrolling(false) in various combinations. It either scrolls or line wraps inside the EditText, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround for this. I make each individual line a HorizontalScrollView. Then I can scroll a long line. This is less elegant than scrolling the whole view, but it works.

```
public class OrItem extends HorizontalScrollView implements TextWatcher {
public OrItem(Context context) {
    m_layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    m_nameSelector = new Spinner(context);
    m_contSelector = new Spinner(context);
    m_matchString = new EditText(context);
    m_matchString.setMaxLines(1);
    m_matchString.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    m_matchString.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
}
public boolean setup(...) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams ww = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    addView(m_layout);
    m_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    m_layout.addView(m_nameSelector, ww);
    m_layout.addView(m_contSelector, ww);
    m_matchString.addTextChangedListener(this);
    m_layout.addView(m_matchString, ww);
}
```